# Как изменить размер label-a на маркере?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть маркер, а на нём label-цифры. Как можно сделать для них отступы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать MarkerWithLabel при создании маркера. 
в [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/y3M4u/) описывается процесс вставки своего блока в поле labelContent.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: homeLatLng,
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "<div class='arrow'></div><div class='inner'>$425K</div>",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    isClicked: false
});
```

а далее css делаете отступ.

Answer (score 1):

```
new google.maps.Size(x,y)
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, тут:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Это ссылка на офф.описания именно того, о чём вы спрашиваете.